# Change array property's items names in GDI+ application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, colors, properties, gdi+

In a GDI+ application on Visual Studio, I want to change the item names of the `colors` property, which is an array. Right now, I can see them as  `[0]` & `[1]`, which makes it difficult for me to see what they represent. I would prefer to set personalized names for them.

Also, if possible, I would like to disable the `...` button on the right of the `colors`property, where I can add, remove and change the colors.

This is all shown in the picture below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l49qF.png]

Comment: `Colors` is an array, you can't make it a dictionary. You'll have to make your own construct to do something like this.

Comment: If you create your own PropertyGrid, you can do anything you want.

Comment: if you get rid of the button how will you change either of the inner color values?

Answer (score 1):

This is an array, it is named like this. If you want to have names, you could use a tupple or a pair or a dictionnary in your object as a property. In the current state, it is impossible.